# Delegating jquery Deferred to another Deferred

Tags: jquery-deferred

I'm trying to chain jquery deferreds such that a promise is resolved by another Deferred.

My use case is: I have an object that returns a promise to a client,

```
var p1 = $.Deferred();

// client gets a promise for a future result
function get() {
    return p1.promise();    
}
```

At some time in the future, something else delivers the result that `p1` should ultimately resolve to as either a value, or another promise:

```
// at some time in the future, something else completes p1 with either a value:
function resolveWithValue(val) {
    p1.resolve(val);
}

// .. or with a promise
function resolveWithPromise(promise) {
    // ... in which case we want p1 to resolve/reject/wait based on the promise arg:

    // 1st try - doesn't work - p1.done() yields a promise, not the promise's value;
    p1.resolve(promise);

    // 2nd try - this works, but-- is there a better syntax?
    promise
        .done(function(v) { p1.resolve(v); })
        .fail(function() { p1.reject(); });
}
```

My question is, is there a better syntax for that last line ('2nd try')?  I believe other promise libs allow chaining like in '1st try' but I need $.Deferred() here.

I'm not looking for advice on how to restructure the code to avoid the chaining, I can't change it (nor can I share it, thus the contrived example).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what the question is?  You can use `p1.then(fn)` where `fn` returns either another promise or a value - either will work.  If it returns a promise, it will chain the promises.  If it returns a value, that value will be passed down the chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I added some details to explain why (I believe, possibly misguidedly) that `.then()` isn't relevant here.  In your proposal, wouldn't `fn` have to know of the existence of `p2` at the time `fn` was evaluated ?

Comment: You aren't showing enough of the real code for me to understand the problem you think you have.  In my suggestion of `p1.then(fn)`, `fn` is executed only after p1 has resolved.  You have to know at that point whether you're returning another promise or just a value and you can just return whichever it is at that time.  Nothing has to be known about whether it's another promise or not until `fn` is called AFTER `p1` is resolved.

Comment: Somewhat, by definition, if you don't yet know how to resolve `fn` yet when it's called, then you return a promise and resolve that promise later when you do know and you can always resolve it with either another promise or a value when it's time to resolve it. If you resolve it with a promise, it extends the promise chain.  If you resolve it with a value, that value is passed back through the chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 revised the sample code again, let me know if not more clear.  I'm not able to share the real code, besides it definitely wouldn't make things clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the actual problem.  If you don't know whether you will have a value or a promise, you return a promise and then at resolve time, you either resolve with a value or resolve with another promise.  Resolving with another promise will automatically chain it.

Comment: @jfriend00 by "resolving with another promise will automatically chain it", do you mean the expression with the "1st try" comment ?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fo9h9dd1/

Comment: Better illustration (and, runnable) illustration of what I'm trying to do:  http://jsfiddle.net/tariksbl/zqnjhvj9/

Comment: It looks like it's a jQuery promise issue not supporting the Promises/A+ capability of resolving with a promise as it works with Chrome's built-in promises: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n8p38e5n/ and I would assume it would work with Q or Bluebird (I use Bluebird extensively in a node.js project) since they fully support the standards and jQuery does not.

Comment: Indeed..  I'm looking for a workaround for a jquery shortcoming.

Comment: @tariksbl Note, workaround. Appear that when `value` is a `deferred.promise` object , expecting `done` or other `deferred` method. Perhaps similar to "2nd try" , though within body of `rollForward` http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/zqnjhvj9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Chaining Deferreds

If you want to treat `p1` as a delegate of `p2`, connect them like so:

```
p2.then(p1.resolve, p1.reject, p1.notify)
```

Then, for example, if you call `p2.resolve(x)`, it will call `p1.resolve(x)`.

### Why would you do this?

One concrete example: calling $.get() from inside a setTimeout callback, inside a helper function:

```
// Sends a GET request to `url` after `delayMs`.
// Returns a jQuery promise.
function startDelayedRequest(url, delayMs) {
    var p1 = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var p2 = $.get(url);
        p2.then(p1.resolve, p1.reject, p1.notify);
    }, delayMs);
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: This was the code in the "1st try" comment - I was surprised to see that p1 resolved to a promise (p2), not the val p2 yielded when resolved.